# Is there any other ways to sort dataframe column values by Date (Year-Month) on

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Initially it was in year-month order but when sum by month operation performed, the output were by-default sorted in ascending order.

Operation performed: `sales=sales.groupby([(sales['Date'])]).sum()`

`print(sales)`

**Output:**

```
        Quantity
Date              
2010-Dec      3130
2011-Jan      5230
2011-Feb      1710
2011-Mar      1904
```

Expected output:

```
        Quantity
Date              
2010-Dec      3130
2011-Jan      5230
2011-Feb      1710
2011-Mar      1904
```

Tried:  `sales=sales.sort_values(by=sales.index, ascending=False)` but didn't work.
Tried to reset index by: `sales=(sales.groupby([(sales['Date'])]).sum()).reset_index(False)` and
sort but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can do it convert to datetime them we do `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.index).argsort()]
df
          Quantity
Date              
2010-Dec      3130
2011-Jan      5230
2011-Feb      1710
2011-Mar      1904
```